# Facebook like a "Product" og:type, not a link

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, product, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to figure out how to add a Facebook "like" button on a product page that when clicked displays a post on the user's Wall saying something like "John Smith liked a **product**" instead of "John Smith liked a link"?

I thought this would be a feature of the Facebook og:type tag. For a product page on my website www.luhsetea.com, I have the following tags:

```
<html lang="en" class="no-js" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# luhsetea: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/luhsetea#">

<meta property="og:title" content="Spice of Your Life" />
<meta property="og:type" content="luhsetea:product" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.luhsetea.com/products/spice-of-your-life" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Luhse Tea" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content=" APP_ID " />
<meta property="og:description" content="Honey, milk, and tea blend with our spices perfectly!&nbsp; See what you can make, with these spi..." />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0077/8972/products/spice-of-your-life_medium.jpg?101788" />
```

I've included the JS SDK and code required for the like button:

```
<fb:like href="http://www.luhsetea.com/products/spice-of-your-life" send="false" layout="button_count" width="180" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

I've added an App in my Facebook Developer account, plus an Action called "Like" to an Object called "Product" in the Open Graph settings on the App configuration page. After doing this facebook gave me the code for the `<meta property="og:type" content="luhsetea:product" />` tag.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting confused about the difference between the Like button and Open Graph verbs and actions - they're two separate things, and any verbs you add to your applications Open Graph settings won't affect a Like button.

If you really want to use an Open Graph 'like' verb (and I'd recommend against it as it's confusing with a normal FB 'like', and probably won't be approved by FB) then you'll have to integrate with the Open Graph directly, as per https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/tutorial/#publish

Note: If you do use an Open Graph 'like' verb, you wont get the benefit of a user liking your product with a Like button - that is, the ability to connect with those users when you publish content to your products Page.

If you just want a Like button and to remove the 'a link' part from the News Feed, set your `og:type` to simply `product`

Comment: Thanks for your reply - yes, it seems I am getting confused between two different things. What you describe in the last sentence of your answer is what I'm looking for. I tried editing the `og:type` tag but the products are still updating my status as "John Smith liked a link" on my Facebook Wall. It also causes this error on the Facebook debugger (http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug): "Object at URL 'http://www.luhsetea.com/products/nice-coconuts' of type 'og_products:product' is invalid because it the specified fb:app_id 'APP_ID' is not the owner of specified og:type."

Comment: The error is a bug in the linter - see https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/285421101492706?browse=search_4f0b2027109043d03695483. It should be fixed later this week.

I don't think that's related to not changing the look of the story in the news feed tho.

Comment: Hmm, looking more into this, I don't think the news feed stories look at the og:type at all, and we always display 'link' unless a user hits like on the FB Page itself. Sorry :(

Comment: (But you do get the image and description, so it's easy to make it clear what the user is liking)

Comment: Ok, although it's unfortunate I can't customise the post at least I now know what can and cannot be done. Appreciate your help with this @mrtom, thanks :)